# overloaded << operator function : unresolved external symbol error

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I've overloaded << operator to print the address in pointer member of a class. However, it throws the following error (using Visual Studio 2017). Using a normal class method does the job.

Any leads?

**Error:**

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __cdecl IntroSmartPointers::operator<<(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,class IntroSmartPointers::AutoPtr<class IntroSmartPointers::Resource> const &)" (??6IntroSmartPointers@@YAAEAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@AEAV12@AEBV?$AutoPtr@VResource@IntroSmartPointers@@@0@@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl IntroSmartPointers::main(void)" (?main@IntroSmartPointers@@YAXXZ)
```

**Code:**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

namespace SmartPointers {
    template<class T>
    class AutoPtr {
    private:
        T* m_ptr;

    public:
        // constructor
        AutoPtr(T* ptr = nullptr)
            : m_ptr(ptr)
        {}

        // destructor
        ~AutoPtr() {
            delete m_ptr;
        }

        friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const AutoPtr<T>& ptr);
    };

    template<class T>
    ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const AutoPtr<T>& ptr) {
        out << ptr.m_ptr;
    }

    class Resource {
    public:
        Resource() { cout << "Resource(): acquired\n"; }
        ~Resource() { cout << "~Resource: destroying...\n"; }

        void sayHi() {
            cout << "Hi\n";
        }
    };
}

void main() {
    SmartPointers::AutoPtr<Resource> ptr{ new Resource{} };
    cout << ptr << endl;
}
```

Comment: Try moving `main()` to the outside of the namespace

Comment: main() moved outside of namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `friend` declares non-template operator.
In this case, you can define a friend function inside of the class body, or try the following:

```
template<typename T>
class AutoPtr {
  // ...


  template<typename U>
  friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const AutoPtr<U>& ptr);
};

template<class T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const AutoPtr<T>& ptr) {
  out << ptr.m_ptr;
  return out; // You missed this part too
}
```

see *Template friend operators* section in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend
And `main` should return `int` instead of `void`.